# I want to upload an image to my blog with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am creating a small blog with node.js, my blog works perfectly locally, but I would like to add images to my article, I already use bootstrap to display my input but at the node. i can not save my image can you help me please?

I use Mongoose as an online server
(I work under linux)

server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
swig = require('swig'),
path = require('path'),
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
app = express();

app.use(express.logger());
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.engine('html', swig.renderFile);

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname+'/views');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://**:**@**.mlab.com:**/blog');
var Article = mongoose.model('Article', {title: String, content: 
String, updated: Date}); 

app.get('/', function(req, res){

    Article.find({}).sort({updated: -1}).exec(function(err, articles){
        if(err){throw err;}

        data = {title: 'Mon super blog', articles: articles};
        res.render('index', data);
    })
 });

app.get('/article/:id', function(req, res){
    var article = Article.findById(req.params.id, function(err, 
article){
        if(err){throw err}
            var data = {article: article, title: article.title};
        res.render('article', data);
    });
 });


 app.post('/update/:id', function(req, res){
    Article.update({ _id : req.params.id}, {
        title: req.body.titre, content: req.body.contenu, updated: new 
 Date()
    },
    function(err){
        if(err){throw err;}
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});

app.get('/edit/:id', function(req, res){
    var article = Article.findById(req.params.id, function(err, 
article){
        if(err){throw err}
        var data = {article: article, title: 'Modifier ' 
 +article.title};
        res.render('edit', data);
    })
})


app.get('/destroy/:id', function(req, res){
    Article.remove({ _id : req.params.id}, function(err){
        if(err){throw err;}
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});

app.get('/create', function(req, res){
    var data = {title: 'Ajouter un article'};
    res.render('create', data);
});

app.post('/store', function(req, res){
    var article = new Article({
        title: req.body.titre,
        content: req.body.contenu,
        updated: new Date()
    });

    article.save(function(err, article){
        if(err){throw err;}
        res.render('created');
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('App running http://localhost:3000');
```

create.html

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block content %}

<form role="form" action="/store" method="post">

<div class="form-group">
<label for="titre">Titre</label>
<input type="text" name="titre" class="form-control" 
placeholder="titre de l'article" required>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="titre">Titre</label>
    <label for="contenu">Contenu de l'article</label>
    <textarea name="contenu" class="form-control" placeholder="Contenu 
de l'article" rows="3" required></textarea>
</div>

<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Telecharger une image</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="img">
    </div>
</form>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Ajouter </button>

</form>


{% endblock %}
```

article.html

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block content %}

<span class="pull-right"><a class="btn btn-danger remove" 
href="/destroy/{{article.id}}">Le bouton magique</a></span>

<h1>{{article.title}}</h1>


<p>{{article.content}}</p>

<span class="date">
Mis à jour {{article.updated.getDate()}} / 
{{article.updated.getMonth() +1}} / {{article.updated.getFullYear()}}
</span>

<div class="pull-right">
<a href="/edit/{{article.id}}" class="btn btn-default">Modifier</a>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Hello I want to save the image and save it and publish on my blog

Comment: Do you want to upload image from ui? or just give the external url?

Comment: I want to download an image from my computer

Comment: added answer try that.

Comment: on my server.js I do not modify anything other than the code you just sent me ?

Comment: when I click on submit nothing happens

Comment: updated code check that and also given link for reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally here is the solution I had found last week, I want to thank you

server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
multer = require('multer'),
swig = require('swig'),
path = require('path'),
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
app = express(); 

//app.use(express.logger());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.engine('html', swig.renderFile);

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname+'/views');




mongoose.connect('mongodb://*:*@ds145438.mlab.com:45438/blog');
var Article = mongoose.model('Article', {title: String,img: String, 
content: String, updated: Date}); 

app.get('/', function(req, res){

    Article.find({}).sort({updated: -1}).exec(function(err, articles){
        if(err){throw err;}

        data = {title: 'Mon super blog', articles: articles};
        res.render('index', data);
    })
 });

 app.get('/article/:id', function(req, res){
    var article = Article.findById(req.params.id, function(err, 
 article){
        if(err){throw err}
            var data = {article: article, title: article.title};
        res.render('article', data);
    });
  });


 app.post('/update/:id', function(req, res){
    Article.update({ _id : req.params.id}, {
        title: req.body.titre,
        img: '/uploads/' + req.file.filename,
        content: req.body.contenu,
        updated: new Date(),
    },
    function(err){
        if(err){throw err;}
        res.redirect('/');
    });
  });

  var upload = multer({dest: __dirname + '/public/uploads'});

  app.post('/create',upload.single('img'), function(req,res)
  {

    console.log('req : ', req.file)
    var article = new Article({
    title: req.body.titre,
    img: '/uploads/' + req.file.filename,
    content: req.body.contenu,
    updated: new Date(),
   });

   article.save(function(err, article){
    if(err){throw err;}
    res.render('created');
   });
 });


 app.get('/edit/:id', function(req, res){
    var article = Article.findById(req.params.id, function(err, 
 article){
        if(err){throw err}
        var data = {article: article, title: 'Modifier ' + 
 article.title};
        res.render('edit', data);
    })
 })


 app.get('/destroy/:id', function(req, res){
    Article.remove({ _id : req.params.id}, function(err){
        if(err){throw err;}
        res.redirect('/');
    });
 });

  app.get('/create', function(req, res){
    var data = {title: 'Ajouter un article'};
    res.render('create', data);
  });

  app.post('/store', upload.single('img'), function(req, res){

    console.log('req.body : ', req.body)
    console.log('req.file : ', req.file)
    var article = new Article({
        title: req.body.titre,
        img: '/uploads/' + req.file.filename,
        content: req.body.contenu,
        updated: new Date(),
    });

    article.save(function(err, article){
        if(err){throw err;}
        res.render('created');
    });
   });

  app.listen(3000);
  console.log('App running http://localhost:3000');
```

article.html

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block content %}

<span class="pull-right"><a class="btn btn-danger remove" href="/destroy/{{article.id}}">Le bouton magique</a></span>

<h1>{{article.title}}</h1>

    <img src="{{article.img}}" alt="img">


<p>{{article.content}}</p>

<span class="date">
Mis à jour {{article.updated.getDate()}} / {{article.updated.getMonth() +1}} / {{article.updated.getFullYear()}}
</span>

<div class="pull-right">
<a href="/edit/{{article.id}}" class="btn btn-default">Modifier</a>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Hey I have stuck with the same issue. Can you please look https://github.com/michelson/Dante/issues/168 here. Pleaseee

Answer (score 0):

You can use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) library to upload and save file into local storage and save relative path to your database.

```
var multer = require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, './uploads')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
    }
});
var upload = multer({storage: storage});

app.post('/create',upload.single('img'), function(req,res)
{
  var article = new Article({
    title: req.body.titre,
    content: req.body.contenu,
    updated: new Date(),
    // you can store path here
  });

  article.save(function(err, article){
    if(err){throw err;}
    res.render('created');
  });
});
```

You can read more at [here](https://medium.com/@bmshamsnahid/nodejs-file-upload-using-multer-3a904516f6d2)

But what I would suggest is use any cloud storage like s3 or Azure storage and store file there from client side directly and pass that url to server to store in DB.

> Client > Requst server for temporary cred > upload file using that
>   cred > call `/create` on server including url.

Comment: Why is it better to store on s3 than locally?

Comment: as if you are storing files on locally, you can not scale the application easily and apart from that you are keeping it on volatile storage and served from there and your local storage is not much optimized for serving the content, so you can better utilize these services and your app should not be dependent on any hardware or other things. keep all the things loosely coupled